# Find an element of order $3$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/14)^*$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/42Z)^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

- Find an element of order $3$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z})^∗$

The elements in $(\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z})^∗$ are 
$$1, 3,5,9,11,13$$
I've raised all of them to the power $3$ and found that $13$ is an element of order $3$.

- Find an element of order $3$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z})^∗$

I can do the same thing to find the element of order $3$, but there are $12 $ elements, and it takes time by hand.

Is there another way to do it ? I know that $(\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z})^∗$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z})^∗\times (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^∗$.

Comment: $13$ is not an element of order $3$ modulo $14.$

Comment: $13=-1$ in $(\Bbb Z/14\Bbb Z)^{\times}$ has of course order $2$, since $(-1)^2=1$. Also $9^3\equiv 1\bmod 14$ and $9^2\not\equiv 1 \bmod 14$. Same with $11$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you I miscalculated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Chinese remainder theorem*
$$\mathbf Z/42\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/14\mathbf Z,\quad\text{ hence }\quad(\mathbf Z/42\mathbf Z)^\times\simeq (\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z)^\times\times(\mathbf Z/14\mathbf Z)^\times. $$
Now $9$ has order $3\bmod 14$ and $1$ has order $1\bmod 3$, so the pair $(1,9)$ has order $3$ in the product ring.

Given that a Bézout's relation between $14$ and $3$ is $5\cdot 3-14=1$, the pair $(1,9)$ corresponds to
$$9\cdot5\cdot 3-1\cdot 14=121\equiv -5\mod 42.$$

Answer (score 0):

$5^3\equiv -1\pmod{42}$, so $5$ has order $6$. Then $5^2$ has order $3$.

Comment: you have also identified $-5$ [since $(-5)^3=-(5^3)\equiv1],$ in case OP wanted more than one element,

Answer (score 0):

If $x^3\equiv1\mod{42}$ then $x^3\equiv1\mod{14}$ and $\mod 3$.

If $x^3\equiv1\mod{14}$ then $x\equiv1,9,$ or $11\mod {14}$.

If $x^3\equiv1 \mod 3$ then $x\equiv1 \mod 3$.

If $x\equiv1, 9, $ or $11 \mod {14}$, then $x\equiv 1,9,11,15,23,25,29,37,$ or $39 \mod {42}.$

Which of these is $\equiv1 \mod 3$?

Which of those is $\not\equiv1 \mod 42$?

Comment: Can you explain how you found x = 1,9,11, 15,23,25,29,37,39 mod 42 please

Comment: I added multiples of $14$ to $1, 9, $ and $11$